# Redux Function are Called automatically again and again when app is in foreground

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist

I'm using firebase Phone Authentication using react-native-firebase. Yesterday the whole module was working correctly, but now it displays an error

cannot read property confirm of undefined

When the app is in the foreground, redux keeps firing the reducers.

[It keeps changing my object ComfirmResult to null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9xCs.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sardar, please post the relevant minimal reproducible example code in your question, don’t post it somewhere else on the internet; make it easy for people to help you and you’ll get more and better answers. How to post a Stack Snippet (in your question): meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/7515189